# MySQL - Remove substring from an entry

Tags: mysql, sql, substring, sql-like

My 'Location' table contains 6 columns. (ID, Name, Alias, Area, X, Y)

Example of some entries from the 'Name' column:

```
Blackwood Highschool, Paris, France

Hilltop Market, Barcelona, Spain

Roundwell Plaza, Melbourne, Australia

Rurk Mount, Moscow, Russia(mountain)

History Museum, Prague, Czech Republic

Narrow River (river), Bombay, India
```

Some entries include "(mountain)", "(river)" or "(...)" within the name (8 different ones). I don't know why the table was created this way. It should have had an extra column for this data, but well.

I want to remove just the "(...)" substrings from the Location Names. I don't know how to do it, it's something like this so you get an idea:

```
DELETE FROM 'Location' 
WHERE 'Name'
LIKE '%(%)%';
```

I know this would delete the whole row, but I just want to remove the (%) term from the 'Name' string.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you only have 8 variations, and this is a one time thing, you could do it with a replace.

```
update location
  set name = replace(name , '(river)','')
  where name like '%(river)%';
```

Comment: Exactly, it's just a one time thing. This worked perfectly for the 8 variations.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with brute force string operations:

```
select concat(left(name, instr(name, '(') - 1),
              right(name, length(name) - instr(val, ')'))
             )
```

Actually, you want this in an `update` statement:

```
update location
    set name = concat(left(name, instr(name, '(') - 1),
                      right(name, length(name) - instr(val, ')'))
                     )
    where name like '%(%)%';
```

You do *not* want `delete`, because that deletes entire rows.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of DELETE, do UPDATE, something like:

```
UPDATE Location
SET Name = LEFT(Name,LOCATE('(',Name)-1)
WHERE LOCATE('(',Name) > 0
```

Syntax is off a bit I think.

Answer (score 0):

I made this example for you:

```
set @name = "Rurk Mount, Moscow, Russia(mountain)";

set @fir = locate("(",@name);
set @las = locate(")",@name);

set @lef = left(@name,@fir-1);

set @word = substr(@name,@fir+1,@las-@fir-1);

select @fir,@las,@lef,@word,concat(@lef,' ',@word);
```

In this way you can see a way to accomplish your task.